# How to use Swiper 8.4.4 carousel with Nuxt3 plugins?

Tags: typescript, nuxt.js, swiper.js, nuxtjs3

How to use Swiper 8.4.4 carousel with Nuxt3 plugins ? Component registration dont'work for me.

I have plugin file swiper.client.js in /plugins directory.

My code look like this:

```
import { Swiper, SwiperSlide } from 'swiper/vue';

export default defineNuxtPlugin(nuxtApp => {
  nuxtApp.vueApp.use(Swiper, SwiperSlide);
});
```

... <swiper> component don't work and a I have following warning in console:

```
runtime-core.esm-bundler.js:40 \[Vue warn\]: A plugin must either be a function or an object with an "install" function.
```

Comment: Do you really need to register like this?  You can just import the Component or composable and use that I think here is some example https://swiperjs.com/vue

Answer (score 0):

You could use `nuxt-swiper` which is built for Nuxt 3 (developed by @cpreston321).

[Documentatation](https://github.com/cpreston321/nuxt-swiper)

Install it with

```
# npm
npm install nuxt-swiper

# yarn
yarn add nuxt-swiper

#pnpm
pnpm add nuxt-swiper
```

Register it in your `nuxt.config.ts`

```
export default defineNuxtConfig({
  modules: ['nuxt-swiper']
  swiper: {
    // Swiper options
    //----------------------
    // prefix: 'Swiper',
    // styleLang: 'css',
    // modules: ['navigation', 'pagination'], // all modules are imported by default
  }
})

// or inline config
export default defineNuxtConfig({
  modules: [['nuxt-swiper', {
    // Swiper options
  }]]
})
```

Then use it as you would a component, passing the Swiper modules and options that you want to import. Refer to the documentation for the module options.

There is a [demo](https://stackblitz.com/github/cpreston321/nuxt-swiper/tree/main/examples/swiper-basic?file=app.vue) to give you an idea as well.

Comment: Please edit your question and paste a minimal code how to install it and maybe use it. It's a bad practice to post an answer with only links to documentation etc. Links might change and not work.